Dynamically pivoting columns in Azure Data Factory stalls due to error?
Problem:
I have multiple rows with identical MATNR but different content per columns. I want to make one single unique row out of it and merging the different contents in multiple rows.
This problem was already solved here. In image 1 you see the raw data that comes in.

After that I do a window transformation (as stated in the link) to create a new column called "ws". It's over settings are "MATNR" and "CHARG". This is the expression:
concat(CHARG, toString(rowNumber()) )
There I concatenate count-numbers to the "CHARG" column. The result looks like this:

I then do a pivot transformation configured like:

Now the final result is fine when only doing these transformations with one ID.
But I have plenty of them. Now ADF seems to stuck since it creates ~65k columns based on ~ 25k rows.

Is my configuration wrong? Or an easier way to do so? Because when I run the pipeline it takes 2hours and then it cancels itself since it cannot finish it. Or is there a looping configuration issue resulting in getting never a result anyways?
best regards!
raw data for testing:
MATNR;LABST;LGORT;LGPBE;CHARG;CLABS
8200451459;0.0;SU60;101_65-413;Supermarkt;
8200451459;0.0;SU50;101_55-413;Supermarkt;
8200451459;0.0;B417;O 34 01 01;ZN;
8200451459;0.0;B405; ;ZN;
8200451459;0.0;SU15; ;Supermarkt;
8200451459;0.0;B417;O 34 01 01;ZI;
8200451459;0.0;SU30;116_35-413;Supermarkt;
8200451459;0.0;UBWL; ;ZN;
8200451459;515.0;581;O 34 01 01;ZN;163
8200451459;515.0;581;O 34 01 01;ZG;352
8200451459;0.0;SU40;116_45-413;Supermarkt;
8200451459;0.0;586; ;ZD;


what error are you getting? and can you provide your expected output for the sample input?

Job failed due to reason: at Sink 'XXXXX': java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - 20480\nHint: Number of columns processed may have exceeded limit of 20480 columns

For every MATNR there will be many rows, for each row the dynamically columns are created. so you will be getting more columns which exceeding the limit. so please choose different condition or criteria to creating a single row for each MATNR

What I don't get - The columns should not more then 100 in total or so. Because they don't stack individually to each up. The "CHARG" Types valures are limited to 5 or so. And there are maybe 5k distinct "LGPBE" and "LGORT" values. For example I will have LABSTxZN3, LABSTxZN4, LABSTxZN5 and so on. But probably not more then 10.

In other words: When I have the exact same raw data as shown in my post above but with a different ID and maybe slighlty different values - the amount of rows should not increase at all. They should stay the exact same amount. Or is this a wrong assumption?

Sorry for flodding - but in the Pivot function to I need to group over MATNR or MATNR and CHARG ?


Job failed due to reason: at Sink 'XXXXX': java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - 20480\nHint: Number of columns processed may have exceeded limit of 20480 columns.

According to the document The default Maximum columns value is 20480 for the delimited text source, your Azure Data Factory (ADF) pipeline has exceeded the limit of 20,480 columns. That may be the reason to get above error. To get your requirement, use MATNR column as Group by  instead of id column

ws column as pivot key, mention pivoted as required, then you won't get that much of columns for every MATNR value as shown below:

